# MySQL single table subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a problem where I wish to take all the rows in a table with `col5=2206` and then select all other rows with col2 and col3 containing the same combination of col2 and col3 as that of col5 (fi. in the example below col2=2, col3=6)

I also wish to filter the returned rows to those with certain values in col5 (fi. col5=4000).

```
('101', '2', '6', '2009-12-31', '2206', 'Exempt', '0', '0', '0', '4', '5'),  
('102', '2', '6', '2009-12-31', '4000', 'Exempt', '-1', '0', '0', '4', '5'),  
('103', '2', '6', '2009-12-31', '1200', '', '1', '0', '0', '4', '5');
```

I have tried various sub query statements. But can't get anything to work as on one table. Is this possible or do I need to create a bigger script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use self joins to achieve what you want.

```
 Select t2.*
   From table t1
   Join table t2 on ( t2.col2 = t1.col2 and t2.col3 = t1.col3 )
  Where t1.col5 = '2206'
    And t2.col5 <> '2206' -- replace that with specific filters like t2.col5 = '4000'
      ;
```

Comment: Many thanks - this works quickest - just needed to add an alias to make second line From table t1 As t2.

Answer (score 0):

Better you should go with JOINS, but you need subqueries then you can try this :

```
select a.* from table a where 
a.col2 in (select col2  from table  where col5=a.col5) 
and 
a.col3 in (select col3  from table  where col5=a.col5) 
and a.col5=4000;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rather suggest you to do this using back end code rather than SQL , coz it may give you performance issues .

Comment: I'd rather that not using the highly optimized db data storage and query engine will result in performance penalties.